# ASP.NET Project framework error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a legacy project that I have inherited.  It was an absolute utter and complete mess.  Within version control, every single file was revision 1.  Long story short it was completely broken and did not come close to compiling.  dll refresh files were pointed to files outside of version control, and the dll's that were versioned were the WRONG ones.  Hours and hours lost just getting this to build in VS2008.

At any rate, according to the project details the project targets framework 3.5.  However, an 401.2 authorization error I get in my browser when debugging the project says that framework 2.0.* was being used.

Has anyone had seen this before, or know of a remedy?

Comment: Check your IIS configuration.  See what ASP version the Virtual Directory is attempting to use.

Comment: I'm new to ASP.NET in VS, but I think am just using the internal debug server WebServer.exe and not full blown IIS.  Could that be part of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3.5 version of the framework is just some additional features (such as Linq) integrated into v2.0 of the CLR. So, even if your project shows a target of 3.5, it is still running on version 2.0 of the CLR.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history#.NET_Framework_3.5

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I'm trying to sort out another error and didn't know if this was part of the problem.  Thanks for giving me another potential problem to eliminate.

Answer (score 1):

Check IIS to see which version of the framework the worker process is using.  Also check any class files you may also be compiling to make sure that they are using the same framework version.